# как настроить rabbitmq на то, чтоб он слушал не только localhost

Tags: rabbitmq

все перебрал -

в документации сказано - https://www.rabbitmq.com/networking.html

я не могу понять как его заставить цеплять это?

операционка - debian(Linux 4.9.0-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.13-1 (2017-02-27) x86_64 GNU/Linux)
rabbitmq - 3.6.9

файлы все положил как написано в документации - он их не видит, или не подцепляет (

Comment: Не видел его никогда и не могу проверить, но документация однозначно говорит: `listeners.tcp.1 = :::5672`

Answer (score 1):

все разобрался - он не хотел работать по  хосту - поставил ИП все заработало